# Bootstrap3 Dropdown Menu Alignment

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am using bootstrap3 for my project and have added a large menu to my tool that I found on a snippets website.

When I added the menu, I am trying to get it to align underneath the button but its off to the right.

I tried this but it didn't change anything.

`.dropdown-large{
    left:inherit
}`

The example code can be found here if desired: http://bootsnipp.com/snippets/featured/large-dropdown-menu

[image]

Here is the CSS behind the menu it self:

```
.dropdown-large {
  position: static !important;
}
.dropdown-menu-large {
  margin-left: 16px;
  margin-right: 16px;
  padding: 20px 0px;
}
.dropdown-menu-large > li > ul {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
.dropdown-menu-large > li > ul > li {
  list-style: none;
}
.dropdown-menu-large > li > ul > li > a {
  display: block;
  padding: 3px 20px;
  clear: both;
  font-weight: normal;
  line-height: 1.428571429;
  color: #333333;
  white-space: normal;
}
.dropdown-menu-large > li ul > li > a:hover,
.dropdown-menu-large > li ul > li > a:focus {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #262626;
  background-color: #f5f5f5;
}
.dropdown-menu-large .disabled > a,
.dropdown-menu-large .disabled > a:hover,
.dropdown-menu-large .disabled > a:focus {
  color: #999999;
}
.dropdown-menu-large .disabled > a:hover,
.dropdown-menu-large .disabled > a:focus {
  text-decoration: none;
  background-color: transparent;
  background-image: none;
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(enabled = false);
  cursor: not-allowed;
}
.dropdown-menu-large .dropdown-header {
  color: #428bca;
  font-size: 18px;
}
@media (max-width: 768px) {
  .dropdown-menu-large {
    margin-left: 0 ;
    margin-right: 0 ;
  }
  .dropdown-menu-large > li {
    margin-bottom: 30px;
  }
  .dropdown-menu-large > li:last-child {
    margin-bottom: 0;
  }
  .dropdown-menu-large .dropdown-header {
    padding: 3px 15px !important;
  }
}
```

How could I go about moving that menu left more?

Update: Here is a fiddle of the issue. Drag the window be be large; you will see how it is a static position on the right side of the page. http://jsfiddle.net/MV9tL/embedded/result/

Comment: There has to be another CSS doing this. Do yo have any other CSS?

Comment: Add your code into a [Bootply](http://www.bootply.com) complete with the issue you are having and add the link to your question. Need to see this re-created.

Comment: It's just the normal bootstrap CSS and the above code - When I make the window bigger, it has a static position with the right side of the screen. Its always like 5 pixels from the right no matter what

Comment: @misterManSam bootply is down right now, cant save anything to it

Comment: There's something for this here which appears to be a smoother experience: http://geedmo.github.io/yamm3/

Comment: Here is a Bootply for the issue that is still unresolved: http://www.bootply.com/m81oWDx3AI If you stretch the screen, you will see the menu is static to the right side of the screen and moves with it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only thing I can think of that doesn't mess up other functions is the following:

**DEMO: http://jsbin.com/raxuli/1**

Don't use !important, be more specific outside the media queries:

```
.dropdown.dropdown-large {
  position: static;
}
```

**Add to end of your css:**

```
@media (min-width: 1300px) { 
    .dropdown-menu-large {
        min-width: 600px; /*needs a width or add width to the stuff inside it */
    }

    .navbar-nav .dropdown.dropdown-large {
        position: relative
    }
}
```